# Showing non-constant strings in java annotation

Tags: java, enums

I would like to use an enum string value in an annotation to a method

```
@Action(action="display", description=Actions.someEnum.toString())
public String displayFunction() {
   ...
}
```

I get an error in my IDE that the attribute value should be a constant. I have even tried using a static final String, but get the same error.

While I can duplicate the enum values, I would like to reuse the enums so that when the enum gets updated, this code get refactored automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: Why does the enum need to be converted to a string and not directly use the enum?

Comment: The description attribute is a string and there are cases when I may want to concat values

Answer (score 2):

You can use the enum in the Action instead.

```
@Action(action="display", descriptionEnum=Actions.someEnum)
public String displayFunction() {
   ...
}
```

You can give the description an empty string as a default and join the two values if they are both present.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control the annotation code so cant change it

Comment: @DarthNinja You can't call a method/run code an annotation. You have more chance of fixing the annotation.